# Show that something is a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm supposed to show that the logit function $f(x) = \log{\frac{pi}{1-pi}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i1} + \beta_2x_{i2} + ... + \beta_7x_{i7}$ is linear. I'm trying to use the definition $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$, but I get a constant term that messes up the calculation. How do I show this?

Comment: HI, welcome to MSE. can you show as a first step relation of $p_i$ and $x_{i1},x_{i2},...$ ?

Comment: I don't really know, I could exponentiate on each side but will that help me?

Comment: absolutely not, it is better to write log function as a Taylor series.

Comment: https://www.numberempire.com/taylorseriesexpansion.php     I am pretty sure that it can help you. You can conclude $0<p_i<1$ as domain of $\log$ function